# Como agrupar los resultados de consultas

Tags: html, mysql, datatable

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
for ($i=1; $i<= $Cantidad; $i++){ $Activo = 'activo'.$i;`

    $cadenaEtiqueta = $_POST[$Activo];
    $cadenaActivo=substr($cadenaEtiqueta,0,-4);
    $cadenaSubActivo=substr($cadenaEtiqueta,(strlen($cadenaActivo)));
    $intActivo=($cadenaActivo*1);
    $intSubActivo=($cadenaSubActivo*1);
    $instanciaPersistenciaBusquedaBienes = new bienes();
    $instanciaNegocioBusquedaBienes= new n_bienes();
    $resultadoConsultaBusquedaBienes=$instanciaNegocioBusquedaBienes->n_Consulta_BusquedaBienes($intActivo,$intSubActivo);
    $totalConsultaBusquedaBienes=  count($resultadoConsultaBusquedaBienes);}
```

Esto separa una cadena que se recibe con un escáner (etiqueta), envía dos datos ($intActivo,$intSubActivo) a un query en mysql lo que permite generar una consulta , aquí el detalle es que se puede capturar de 1 a n elementos y se requiere que estos sean mostrados en un datatable, al momento de que se procesan las "etiquetas"  estas pueden ser 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.  y esto genera la misma cantidad de consultas 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.... una por cada dupla que se forma con el código anterior para cada etiqueta, pero al momento de intentar imprimir en un datatable solo me esta regresando la ultima consulta,  si es 1 no hay problema, ya con dos es cuando comienza a mostrar el resultado de la segunda dupla, y así sucesivamente si capturamos 5 etiquetas solo me muestra el resultado de la quinta dupla.

Como se podría hacer para que me muestre registro x registro leído en el datatable?.

En el Query al momento que termina de realizar la consulta tengo esta linea

```
while ($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $listaBusquedaBienes[$contador] = new bienes();

$listaBusquedaBienes[$contador]->setCadenaFabricante(utf8_encode($registro['FABRICANTE']));
.
$listaBusquedaBienes[$contador]->
.
$listaBusquedaBienes[$contador]->
. 
$listaBusquedaBienes[$contador]->setCadenaModelo(utf8_encode($registro['MODELO']));
  $contador++;
        }
        return $listaBusquedaBienes;`
```

con este código se va capturando valor por valor traído desde la BD, para posteriormente mandarlo a la pantalla (datatable) con su respectivo get.

Alguna sugerencia ?.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando el código y bueno comencé a realizar algunas pruebas de lo que hacia utilizando "echo"  y después de preguntar aquí, y revisar el código con mi jefe y que me dio otras ideas, se me ocurrió que quizás la respuesta estaba en modificar algunas lineas de código.

```
   `for ($i=1; $i<= $Cantidad; $i++){
    $Activo = 'activo'.$i;
    $cadenaEtiqueta = $_POST[$Activo];

    $cadenaActivo=substr($cadenaEtiqueta,0,-4);
    $cadenaSubActivo=substr($cadenaEtiqueta,(strlen($cadenaActivo)));
    $intActivo=($cadenaActivo*1);
    $intSubActivo=($cadenaSubActivo*1);
    $activoFijo .="'".$intActivo."'";         <--- Separe la estructura original
    $subactivoFijo.="'".$intSubActivo."'";    <--- Separe la estructura original

    if($i< $Cantidad){
        $activoFijo.=',';  <-- Aquí agrupa los elementos en base a la cantidad de entradas
        $subactivoFijo.=','; <-- Aquí agrupa los elementos en base a la cantidad de entradas
    }

    $instanciaPersistenciaBusquedaBienes = new bienes();
    $instanciaNegocioBusquedaBienes= new n_bienes();

    $resultadoConsultaBusquedaBienes=$instanciaNegocioBusquedaBienes->n_Consulta_BusquedaBienes($activoFijo,$subactivoFijo);
    $totalConsultaBusquedaBienes=  count($resultadoConsultaBusquedaBienes);`
```

el resultado de modificar esas lineas básicamente lo que hace cada una de estas seria algo como esto:

$activoFijo.=','; -->Genera una linea de texto así: '10001010','10003453','10000322'..

$subactivoFijo.=','; -->Genera una linea de texto así: '0','1','0'...

Que al final al pasarlo como parámetro me sirve en la consulta que me permite cambiar en el Where la condición utilizarla de la siguiente manera:

```
WHERE 
     control.bienes.Activo IN ($intActivo) 
AND control.bienes.SubActivo IN ($intSubActivo)";
```

Esta condición funciona por duplas entre el $intActivo y el $intSubActivo que finalmente permite que la consulta obtenga los registros dados por la cantidad de entradas que se generan al escanear los códigos de barras.

Saludos